# Galois representations and pro-étale Site

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

On a scheme, we can define the pro-étale site. This is an improvement over the étale site in that we can define the $\ell$-adic cohomology as the sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Z}_\ell }$ instead of as a limit. We can also define $\mathbb{Z}_\ell(1):=\lim \mu_{\ell^n}\in \text{Ab}(X_{\text{proét}})$ (see Remark 5.2.4 in Bhatt and Scholze, *The pro-étale topology for schemes*, arXiv:[1309.1198](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1198)). Assume that $X$ is defined over some number field $k$ and is smooth and projective. My question is if
$$H^n_{\text{proét}}(X_{\bar{k}},\mathbb{Z}_\ell(i))\cong H^i_{\text{ét}}(X_{\bar{k}},\mathbb{Z}_\ell(i))$$
as Galois modules.

Comment: I think you mean $H^i_{\operatorname{(pro)\acute et}}(X_{\bar k}, \mathbf Z_\ell(i))$ ― you need to base change to the algebraic closure to get a Galois action. Also, what are your assumptions on $X$? Finite type; smooth; etcetera?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are absolutely right! I'll change the post. I'm happy to assume $X$ to be smooth projective, and of course other conditions if necessary.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the right side. If you mean the classically defined $\ell$-adic cohomology groups (as an inverse limit), then this is true essentially by definition (see section 5.6 of Bhatt-Scholze for a more general statement). If instead you mean the \'etale cohomology of the constant sheaf attached to the abelian group $\mathbf{Z}_\ell(i)$, then this is quite false (in degree $1$, this amounts to observing that there are typically many more maps $\pi_1^{et}(X) \to \mathbf{Z}_\ell$ if we give the target the $\ell$-adic topology than if we use the discrete topology).

Comment: Thanks! In section 5.6 of Bhatt-Scholze, the just have a "fixed scheme". Does that for instance mean that be can also consider a finite field?

Comment: Yup, the derived inverse limit construction $H^i(X, R\lim \mathbf{Z}/\ell^n)$ coming out of Jannsen's theory (or the Bhatt-Scholze paper) agrees with the classical inverse limit definition $\lim_n H^i(X, \mathbf{Z}/\ell^n)$ over a finite field: by the Milnor sequence, the obstruction to agreement comes from $\lim^1 H^{i-1}(X, \mathbf{Z}/\ell^n)$, which vanishes over finite fields.